Copy Cells Without Certain Text on Excel Macro
I'm new to VBA. I have this code that works perfectly fine with hundred thousands of data. Any idea how I could keep this code and add any function or code that could skip copying cells that contain "no" and copy the rest of the cells that contains anything.
This code do:
Copy cells isnotblank from column C and paste it to column A
    Function RefRangeFind( _
        ByVal firstRowRange As Range, _
        Optional ByVal DisplayMessage As Boolean = False) _
    As Range
        With firstRowRange.Areas(1).Rows(1)
            Dim cell As Range
            With .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
                Set cell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
                If cell Is Nothing Then
                    If DisplayMessage Then
                        MsgBox "No data found in range """ & .Address(0, 0) _
                            & """ of worksheet """ & .Worksheet.Name & """!", _
                            vbExclamation
                    End If
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End With
            Set RefRangeFind = .Resize(cell.Row - .Row + 1)
        End With
    End Function
    Function IsNoErrorNoBlank( _
        Value As Variant) _
    As Boolean
        If Not IsError(Value) Then
            If Len(Value) > 0 Then IsNoErrorNoBlank = True
        End If
    End Function
    Sub lain()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL")
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = RefRangeFind(.Range("C2:D2"))
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Data = rg.Value: Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
    If Not IsNoErrorNoBlank(Data(r, c)) Then Data(r, c) = Empty
    Next c
    Next r
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End With
    End Sub


Include a condition in If clause to erase cells that contain the word no.
Sub lain()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = RefRangeFind(.Range("C2:D2"))
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Dim Data() As Variant
        Data = rg.Value: Dim r As Long, c As Long
        For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                If InStr(1, Data(r, c), "no", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
                    (Not IsNoErrorNoBlank(Data(r, c))) Then Data(r, c) = Empty
            Next c
        Next r
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End With
End Sub


If you want to delete cells that contain the word no
Sub lain()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Dim rg As Range, noRng As Range
        Set rg = RefRangeFind(.Range("C2:D2"))
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Dim Data() As Variant
        Data = rg.Value: Dim r As Long, c As Long
        For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                If InStr(1, Data(r, c), "no", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    If noRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set noRng = .Cells(r + 1, c)
                    Else
                        Set noRng = Application.Union(noRng, .Cells(r + 1, c))
                    End If
                ElseIf Not IsNoErrorNoBlank(Data(r, c)) Then
                    Data(r, c) = Empty
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
        If Not noRng Is Nothing Then
            noRng.Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Update:

Question: i mean do not copy cells containing "no". Instead go to the next row and copy if it doesn't contain "no".

Sub lain()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = RefRangeFind(.Range("C2:D2"))
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Dim Data() As Variant
        Data = rg.Value
        Dim r As Long, c As Long, bFound As Boolean, iR As Long
        For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            bFound = False
            For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                If Not IsError(Data(r, c)) Then
                    If InStr(1, Data(r, c), "no", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        bFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
            If Not bFound Then
                iR = iR + 1
                For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                    If IsNoErrorNoBlank(Data(r, c)) Then
                        Data(iR, c) = Data(r, c)
                    Else
                        Data(iR, c) = Empty
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next r
        .Range("A2").Resize(iR, UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
    End With
End Sub

Microsoft documentation:

InStr function


Range.Delete method (Excel)


Application.Union method (Excel)


sorry, maybe my explanation is not clear. So, the text "no" is basically there everytime another macro done doing vlookup. Then, after doing another round of vlookup I wish to make the code skip copying "no" and goes to another row. so that it doesn't ruin the existing data.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.
And share what's your expected output.

The 1st snippet clear the content of cells that contains no. The 2nd snippet removes the cells. I don't understand skip copying "no" and goes to another row in your comment.

sorry, i mean do not copy cells containing "no". Instead go to the next row and copy if it doesn't contain "no". But thank you so much for your help!

I've updated the code. Please share sample data and expected output if the code doesn't work as your expected.

Conditionally Copy Specific Values to Another Same-Sized Range

If a value in one range is no error or blank, and if it isn't equal to "No", copy it to another same-sized range.

Sub lain()
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = RefRangeFind(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL").Range("C2:D2"))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns("A:B")
    
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    Dim dData() As Variant: dData = drg.Value
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(sData, 2)
            If IsNoErrorNoBlank(sData(r, c)) Then
                If StrComp(sData(r, c), "No", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' not no
                    dData(r, c).Value = sData(r, c)
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    drg.Value = dData

End Sub


thank you for your help :) It's giving object required on this line                     dData(r, c).Value = sData(r, c). Any idea?
